# How can I reposition pages in InDesign to space them more?

Tags: adobe-indesign, workflow, margin

I am working with **InDesign** with a layout that contains 4 different elements of different sizes.

[image]

However, sometimes these elements bleed over onto another element's page boundaries, and I would like to space them out more:

[image]

I tried looking in the Pages panel, but couldn't find a setting allowing me to position them:

[image]

I know how to do it in Illustrator, but I want to do this in InDesign.

### **How can I space out Pages of different sizes?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the *Page Tool*. With this you can drag the pages around with the mouse or you can select a page and edit the coordinates in the *Control* panel.

[image]

Comment: My brief experimentation with this indicates that for best effect one must do this both in the Master and then in the pages of the actual spread - then duplicate that spread...

Comment: @GerardFalla, yes you are right. The pages don't update dynamically when you change the master. There are many quirks. If you have *Facing pages* turned on, you can't move the pages horizontally. And it's easy to get into some frantic dragging pages around to get the setup you want. This answer is just to point in the right direction.